# INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s) - VSC and python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ethereum

I've been following a tutorial to learn Python and smart contracts (I'm totally new to coding), and while following every step to the letter, VSCode keeps returning the following message >INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Although it still returns whatever action I ask it to do:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json
from web3 import Web3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

install_solc("0.6.0")

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()


compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)
with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)
    # get bytecode

    bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
        "bytecode"
    ]["object"]


# get ABI
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"))
chain_id = 1337
my_address = "0x237d38135A752544a4980438c3dd9dFDe409Fb49"
private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")

# create the contract in python
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

# get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)

# 1. build a transation
# 2. Sign a transation
# 3. Send a transation
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {"chainId": chain_id, "from": my_address, "nonce": nonce})

signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    transaction, private_key=private_key)

private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
# Send the signed transaction
print("Deploying contract...")
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
print("Deployed!")
# working with the contract
# contract address
# Contract ABI

simple_storage = w3.eth.contract(address=tx_receipt.contractAddress, abi=abi)
# Call > simulate making the call and getting the return value, doesn't make a change on the blockchain
# Transact  > actually makes a state change

# Initial value of favorite number
print(simple_storage.functions.retrieve().call())
print("Updating contract...")

store_transaction = simple_storage.functions.store(15).buildTransaction(
    {"chainId": chain_id, "from": my_address, "nonce": nonce + 1}
)
signed_store_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    store_transaction, private_key=private_key)
send_store_tx = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_store_txn.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_store_tx)
print("Updated!")
print(simple_storage.functions.retrieve().call())
```

And the result in the terminal is :

```
PS C:\Users\chret\Documents\demo\web3_py_simple_storage> python deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Deploying contract...
Deployed!
0
Updating contract...
Updated!
15
```

So, I'm fairly confused, should I just ignore the warning "Could not find files for the given pattern(s)" ? Or is there anything I can do to fix it/is it going to create issues as I keep coding in those files? I've tried relocating the folders, including the path in Environment variables/PATH, but it doesn't stop this message from showing up.
It's been doing this from the beginning and nowhere does it show on the video I'm following (freecodecamp 16h video tutorial on youtube about blockchain).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you're importing solcx

during the import it runs solcx\install.py

near the end of that file it has this code

```
try:
    # try to set the result of `which`/`where` as the default
    _default_solc_binary = _get_which_solc()
except Exception:
    # if not available, use the most recent solcx installed version
    if get_installed_solc_versions():
        set_solc_version(get_installed_solc_versions()[0], silent=True)
```

the `_get_which_colc()` function is defined earlier in the file, and runs this line (for windows)

```
response = subprocess.check_output(["where.exe", "solc"], encoding="utf8").strip()
```

which errors and sends the message you are worried about to the console

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

This error is expected, and handled in the `except Exception:` clause (see above)

So nothing to worry about, you can ignore the warning :)

Comment: Struggled with the warning so much, but it is OK. Thanks to your response here, I understand the backend codes. Absolutely true, reference to the python file there, but the exception is not a mistake or error. Once the user installs a version of solc, for instance by `install_solc("0.18.7.0")` or runs the import twice or more, the warning disappears. Because now the program has copied the solc files to the desired root. So, nothing to worry about, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem.
I wasn't able to fix it on my windows environment. But,

The github links to a tutorial to setup the brownie stack in an Ubuntu environment on Windows, and this has been working flawlessly for me. And it's easy to setup.

https://medium.com/@cromewar/how-to-setup-windows-10-11-for-smart-contract-development-and-brownie-e7d8d13555b3

It's not mentioned in the article, but currently (26/11/2021), you will want to install Node v16, and ganache v7.0.0-alpha.2 instead, due to compatibility issues.

Refer to link for NVM & node versions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl

Comment: Thank you Jared, I'm learning cyber-security though tryhackme.com and was thinking of setting up a Linux OS on my computer, now you just achieved to convince me to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

a smart contract man.sol, and it contains two(or one) contract in a file, like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "./SafeERC20.sol";
contract mainContract {
  ... (Any code can be here ...)
}contract childContract {
 ... (Other code here)}
```

and our python file. a.py:

```
import json
import os

import web3.eth
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

from solcx import install_solc, set_solc_version,compile_standard
from dotenv import load_dotenv#here install solidity version
install_solc('v0.8.0')
set_solc_version('v0.8.0')


file_path = "."
name = "main.sol"
input = {
    'language': 'Solidity',
    'sources': {
        name: {'urls': [file_path + "/" + name]}},
    'settings': {
        'outputSelection': {
            '*': {
                '*': ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"],
            },
            'def': {name: ["abi", "evm.bytecode.opcodes"]},
        }
    }
}

output = compile_standard(input, allow_paths=file_path)

contracts = output["contracts"]

with open('compiled_code.json', "w") as file:
    json.dump(output, file)

bytecode = contracts["SC-.sol"]["mainContract"]["evm"]["bytecode"]["object"]

abi = contracts["main.sol"]["mainContract"]["abi"]


# Deploy on local ganache# w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"))
# chainId = 1337
# myAddress = "0x6235207DE426B0E3739529F1c53c14aaA271D..."
# privateKey = "0xdbe7f5a9c95ea2df023ad9......."

#Deploy on rinkeby infura rinkebyw3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/......"))
chainId = 4

myAddress = "0xBa842323C4747609CeCEd164d61896d2Cf4..."
privateKey ="0x99de2de028a52668d3e94a00d47c4500db0afed3fe8e40..."

SCOnline = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress)

transaction = SCOnline.constructor().buildTransaction({
    "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price, "chainId": chainId, "from": myAddress, "nonce": nonce
})

signedTrx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key= privateKey)



txHash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signedTrx.rawTransaction)

txReceipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(txHash)
```